# Sprite animation in Android view

Tags: java, 2d, android, animation, sprites

I'm looking for a way to have different sprite animations in individual Android views.

I try to use LibGDX and AndEngine but most I could find was how to get an Activity with the sprite animation.

Is there a way to accomplish this with native Android or a library?

Thanks for the help. Jose